# Download PYPI packages for specific pypi version (3.7) with bandersnatch

Tags: python, pypi, bandersnatch

I'm trying to mirror the pypi.org repo specifically for packages that are python 3.7

According to the [bandersnatch documentation](https://bandersnatch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filtering_configuration.html#project-regex-matching) it's possible to do this using a filter.
But I'm not sure if that is what I am looking for. I reviewed the documentation for the [PyPi API](https://warehouse.readthedocs.io/api-reference/json.html#project) and I think that the filter based on project regex matching for something like `.*Programming Language :: Python :: 2.*` just checks that the project is available for the version you specify, but doesn't download only that version.

I have tried adding the following to my configuration file also but it wasn't successful in achieving the results I expected. It still downloaded all versions of the requests library

```
[regex_release_file_metadata]
any:release_file.python_version =
   "3.7"
```

Is this the wrong filter to use, or am I just using it in the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

Check the new version of bandersnatch; now you can at least exclude unneeded binary distributions for specific Python minor versions.

From the [docs](https://bandersnatch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filtering_configuration.html#platform-python-specific-binaries-filtering):

> You can also exclude Python versions by their minor version (ex. Python 2.6, 2.7) if you’re sure your mirror does not need to serve these binaries.